# Allow searching for IPv6 addresses

Tags: feature-request, search

I just attempted to search for the IPv6 loopback address, `::1` which is analogous to IPv4's `127.0.0.1`.

Searches for `::1` are fruitless (top search result: [Migrating domains with 1&1](https://serverfault.com/questions/323436/migrating-domains-with-11)), while the `127.0.0.1` searches provide some useful results.  Adding quotes didn't help.

Obviously searching for just ::1 or 127.0.0.1 isn't useful, but in combination with other terms it could be useful.

I don't know what, if any, support the search engine has for IPv4 addresses in general.  It seems less likely to be useful as a generic search, so maybe none.  I'd argue though that `::1` will be an important search term going forward.

While I'm posting, obligatory nag for [IPv6 support for Stack Exchange.](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1617/does-server-fault-plan-to-support-ipv6)

Comment: This a specific case of a broader problem. For example if I wanted to search for `<<` or `-->`, I would also have some problems. Sometimes what you really want to search for is a very specific string of characters, and many search tools seem to not support that.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that it's formatted as code, [code:"::1"](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=code%3a%22%3a%3a1%22) seems to work. Otherwise you need to use [SEDE with code like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/edit/974814):

```sql
select id as [Post Link], body from posts where body like '%::1%'
```